API Platform 3: Edit the authenticated user's profile in a PATCH operation
I am using API Platform 3.2 with Symfony 6.4 to write a REST API.
Users are entities, and each user has a 1-1 relationship with a Profile entity.
For Profile operations, there are two endpoints:

GET /users/me/profile: Return the profile of the currently authenticated user
PATCH /users/me/profile: Update the profile of the currently authenticated user

The GET works fine. I use a custom State Provider to fetch the authenticated user and return their associated Profile.
However, I'm having trouble with the PATCH. I'm not sure how to get it to update the  profile of the authenticated user.
I tried creating a custom State Processor called ProfileStateProcessor, but by the time it gets to ProfileStateProcessor::process(), the $data is already a new Profile object. By default it will try to create a new Profile every call.
How can I make PATCH /users/me/profile select the authenticated user's profile for updating?
I know I could find their profile in the state processor, merge the data from the request, and save that -- but it seems like there has to be a better way.

Relevant code
resources/User/Profile.yaml
App\Entity\User\Profile:
    normalizationContext:
        groups: [ 'profile:read' ]
    denormalizationContext:
        groups: [ 'profile:write' ]
    operations:
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get:
            uriTemplate: 'users/me/profile'
            provider: App\State\User\ProfileStateProvider
        ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch:
            uriTemplate: 'users/me/profile'
            processor: App\State\User\ProfileStateProcessor

src/State/User/ProfileStateProvider.php
<?php

namespace App\State\User;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;

class ProfileStateProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct(private readonly Security $security)
    {
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        $profile = $user->getProfile();

        return $profile;
    }
}

src/State/User/ProfileStateProcessor.php
This solution works, but requires me to check every writable field.
<?php

namespace App\State\User;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProcessorInterface;
use App\Entity\User\Profile;
use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autowire;

class ProfileStateProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        #[Autowire(service: 'api_platform.doctrine.orm.state.persist_processor')]
        private ProcessorInterface $persistProcessor,
        private Security $security,
    ) {
    }

    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        assert($data instanceof Profile);

        // Get the actual profile we want to update from security
        $profile = $this->security->getUser()->getProfile();

        // Compare with $data for every possible update
        if ($data->getTimezone() != $profile->getTimezone()) {
            $profile->setTimezone($data->getTimezone());
        }
        // etc...

        return $this->persistProcessor->process($profile, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
    }
}

